# Extracting Attributes from XML File

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I have a sample XML file that I have parsed in R

```
<ROUGHTDRAFT_FILE MV="00" MMV="00" 
    tId="0000">
     <HEADER Location="Utah" dateCreated="1/1/99">
    </HEADER>

    <COVERSHEET>
       <PRIMIARY_INFO eName="John Smith" pList="XXXXX" 
             type="Remodel" cNumber="00000" 
              policyNumber="00000000000"  />
   </COVERSHEET>
</ROUGHDRAFT_FILE>
```

After I load the XML and name it file I get an error. This is my code:

```
xml <- xmlParse(file)
```

This work fine

When I try to pull the attributes it give me an error

```
EstAttribs <- xpathApply(xml, path="//PRIMIARY_INFO", xml_attrs )

Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "c('XMLDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument')"
```

Any recommendations on how I can fix this? Do I have to specify something for xml_attrs?

Comment: Check any error in your first line `xmlParse`. You have mismatched, misspelled root tags.

Comment: You seem to be mixing functions from the `XML and `xml2` packages which isn't a good idea. What if you use `xpathApply(xml, path="//PRIMIARY_INFO", xmlAttrs )`? That worked for me with the sample file (using the `XML` library). The `xml_attrs` function (with the underscore) is from `xml2`.

Answer (score 2):

MrFlick has already given you one answer. Here is another one that might be useful. As he suggested don't try to mix functions from `XML` library with `rvest` and `xml2`.

```
# here is the rvest and xml2 solution
# rvest calls xml2 since it is a dependency
library(rvest)
xml_file <- read_xml("test.xml")

xml_file %>%
  xml_find_all('//PRIMIARY_INFO') %>%
  xml_attrs('eName') 

[[1]]
        eName         pList          type       cNumber  policyNumber 
 "John Smith"       "XXXXX"     "Remodel"       "00000" "00000000000" 

# this solution is purely using XML - as suggested by  MrFlick
library(XML)
xml_file <- xmlParse("test.xml")
xpathApply(xml_file, path="//PRIMIARY_INFO", xmlAttrs )

[[1]]
        eName         pList          type       cNumber  policyNumber 
 "John Smith"       "XXXXX"     "Remodel"       "00000" "00000000000"
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229508/xml2-in-r-extract-children-attributes-from-parents-everything-is-named-the-sam) SO question might contain useful info for you.